# example.com is working but www.example.com has invalid certificate using an AWS S3 bucket and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, route53

On AWS, I created two S3 buckets.
One for `example.com` and one for `www.example.com`.

I selected the option "Use this bucket to host a website" for `example.com` and selected "Redirect requests" on `www.example.com` pointing the target domain to the `example.com` bucket.

Then I created a CloudFront distribution having the S3 bucket as the origin.
Then I requested and selected the certificate for `example.com`. I also requested a certificate for `*.example.com`.

Then on my Route53, I created an alias `A` which has my CloudFront distribution as the alias target.

I also created another alias `A` with name `www.example.com` and alias target is `example.com`.

However, having done all of these things, `example.com` is now working on browsers but when I entered `www.example.com`, it says `www.example.com` is using an invalid certificate.

I tried to create two CloudFront distributions and each one uses the certificate `example.com` and `*.example.com`, but it says CNAME already exist, so I was not able to add the other one.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Provide the true website name if you want to have answers and help. Also "alias A" is meaningless. In DNS you have `A` or `CNAME` records; and alias is often used as a synonym for CNAME.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  AWS does offer "alias" records that are different from `CNAME`.   They are proxy records where DNS serves an `A` record, but looks up the IP address from a specified host name.   They offer that service for cases where `A` records are required (like the bare domain), but where you are pointing to something with a name that could have a dynamic, changing IP address.

Comment: The DNS does not have "ALIAS" record this is purely something offered by some providers, and I know that but I do not want people to mix what is standard from what is particular of a provider. "alias A" still seems sloppy terminology to me.